# Unable to clear interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to terminate the interval created with `setInterval` if the count goes to 3.
I tried the code below but it is not calling the `alert` inside the `if` block.  Why? Is my  comparison not correct or is something else wrong?

```
 $(window).load(function() {
     var timerId = 1;
     timerId = window.setInterval(function() { 
        timerId = timerId + 1; 
        if(timerId == '3') { 
            alert(timerId);  
            clearInterval(timerId);
         }  
     }, 2000); 
 });
```

Comment: You should be using `===`, as `3 == '3'` is `true` but `3 === '3'` is `false`. The triple-equal operator is recommended because it also compares the data type.

Comment: Dude! consider writing comment on down vote...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try not using the same variable for *everything*

```
$(window).load(function() {
     var timerNum = 1,
         timerId  = window.setInterval(function(){ 
             timerNum++; 
             if( timerNum == 3 ){
                 clearInterval(timerId);
             }  
         }, 2000);  
});
```

You can't use the same variable for the count and the interval, the count is something you update yourself adding 1 every time the callback in the interval executes, while the `setInterval` function returns a unique ID that can later be passed to `clearInterval` to clear that specific interval, and by overwriting that ID with your number the unique ID is lost, and the interval can no longer be cleared.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what `setInterval` returns, so that's clearer why the original code cannot work.

Comment: @FelixKling - Uhm, I can at least try !

Comment: @adeneo Can you suggest me a  good title for my above question?

Comment: I'll pass that on to @FelixKling, as I'm not that good with English (or titles).

Comment: @adeneo: And you think I'm better in either of those ?! :P I can give it a try...

Comment: @FelixKling - Judging by the answers you've given, and that you're living and working in the US, it's rather obvious that your english is better than mine, and I have a real lack in imagination when it comes to titles, names etc.

Comment: I'll just accept the compliment and not insist on *my* lack of imagination :) Have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).load(function() {
     var timerId =1;
     timerCount = window.setInterval(function(){ 
     timerId=timerId+1; 
     if(timerId=='3'){ alert(timerId);  clearInterval(timerCount);}  
}, 2000);  });
```

You have two variables with the same name, change one of the variables names to avoid them 'clashing'.

Answer (score 1):

You are using same variable for storing an integer value and unique interval ID return by [**`window.setInterval`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval). So use different variables , that may fix your problem

```
$(window).load(function() {
     var timerId =1;
     var intId = window.setInterval(function(){ 
     timerId=timerId+1; 
     if(timerId=='3'){ alert(timerId);  clearInterval(intId);}  
}, 2000);  });
```

Comment: what changes you have did?

Comment: `setInterval` does not return an object.